# How to prevent new Test script ids generation in postman tests

Tags: automated-tests, postman, integration-testing, postman-testcase

When I export my postman tests after some changes in some tests, all test script ids in postman collection are changed. It is hard for me to change every id in a big collection before commit. How to avoid ids changing?

[image]

Comment: Seems that is still something to live with: https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/2906

Answer (score 0):

[This issue is fixed by v7.36.1](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/2906#issuecomment-747427152). You will see that ids will be removed with the first export. We can get a sane diff again :)